# How model refers these columns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to Ruby on Rails. I don't understand how methods written in model work. eg.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, dependant: :destroy

  def add_line_items_from_cart(cart)
    cart.line_items.each do |item|
         line_items << item
    end
  end
end
```

I don't understand how line_items are referred here. line_item is not a column of Order table then how does line_items << item work.

P.S. - This example taken from RoR book.

Answer (score 0):

`line_items` work because you have a `order_id` column in the LineItem table.  Rails queries that table for any line items with the corresponding `order_id` and returns them as a collection (actually an `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy`). you can read more about it here http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html